# Inhibit lint message 9007

Tags: c, misra, pc-lint

According to MISRA rule 13.5 the right hand operand of a logical && or || operator shall not contain persistent side effects. Our code is checked with PC-Lint, message 9007 (http://gimpel-online.com/MsgRef.html#9007).

We have code of the form

`if((GET_SIGNAL1() < CONST_1) || (GET_SIGNAL2() == CONST_2) )
  {
    dostuff();
  }`

GET_x are macros, well, getting signal x with some error handling, the later causing **intended** side effects. A rule deviation to MISRA 13.5 is given, now the question is how to suppress the respective messages.

Efforts so far:
Since this is auto generated code I can't put in lint comments directly, putting the comments in through the generator is though and, primarily, hardly traceable.

--e{(9007))} in the macro definition would work, but we also have code like
`foo = GET_SIGNAL1();`
which would cause a function wide deactivation.

Thought about -ecall, too, but it just checks the call itself, not the context of the macro (as I hoped).

edit:

I can't affect neither model nor tool chain. Only parts I can affect are the lint configuration or "glue code" like the macro definitions

Comment: May I ask why you are running lint on generated files? It is generally designed to avoid common issues in hand written c, generated c should be correct and need not be so clear.

Comment: Not sure what kind of magic you'd expect here, you've closed all avenues to an obvious workaround.  Simplest way is to stop violating the rule.  Can be as simple as using | instead of ||.  Next best thing is to isolate this code in its own TU so you can apply the global override.

Comment: @HansPassant Would that not change the behaviour, I think this is relying on short circuiting such that `GET_SIGNAL2` can only be run if `GET_SIGNAL1` is

Comment: @Vality MISRA also applies to autogenerated code. The only difference is the classification of the rules to mandatory, required and advisory change.

Comment: @HansPassant But that would be a bitwise comparison, not an enforcement of executing the second side. Think I know what you mean, but that was a different language

Comment: @Vality Otherwise Appendix E, "Applicability to automatically generated code" wouldn't make much sense

Answer (score 1):

Can you modify the generator to output a new macro like this:

```
#define TEST_SIGNALS(a,b,c,d)   ((a<b) || (c<d))

if (TEST_SIGNALS(GET_SIGNAL1(), CONST_1, GET_SIGNAL2(), CONST_2))
{
   dostuff()
}
```

And disable the warning like this:

```
//lint -emacro(9007, TEST_SIGNALS)
```

Comment: Nice idea, but I can't affect neither model nor tool chain including the generator

Answer (score 0):

We intend to solve the proble above with two Lint runs:

- 1st run with productive code and globally deactivated message 9007
- 2nd run with stubbed macro without the intended side-effect, but nothing but message 9007 activated

Comment: Won't accept this as answer, just for inspiration if you have a similar problem